# ERR_GEN_ZLİB 2 Error in GTA 5

Tags: technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-v

I changed my GTA 5 save folder to finish the game because I have already finished the game in the past. Then I started getting this error: ERR_GEN_ZLİB 2. Verifying game folders and re-downloading the game couldn't help me. When I start the game, my game crashes. For extra information, I tried fixing this problem by changing the save folder multiple times. I launch the game from epic games. I deleted PGTA5 (numbers)  folders which were in save folders.